# XPage Data View add rows not working on server

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I'm working on a pretty simple mobile XPages example using a data view with an add rows event to load in more rows. It works when I preview locally, but not on the server - clicking the link does nothing (no error, no more rows, nothing). I installed Upgrade Pack 1 on Domino 8.5.3 (tried both Windows 2008 and Ubuntu Linux). What can I check and/or enable (debug) to find out why it isn't working on the server?

```
<xe:appPage id="ourFaculty" pageName="ourFaculty" resetContent="false">
    <xe:djxmHeading id="djxmHeading1" label="Our Faculty"
        transition="fade" moveTo="homePage" back="Home">
    </xe:djxmHeading>
    <xe:dataView id="dataView1" rows="8" pageName="displayContact"
        openDocAsReadonly="true">
        <xp:this.facets>
            <xp:link escape="true" text="Load More Rows" id="link1"
                xp:key="pagerBottom">
                <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false">
                    <xp:this.script>
                        <xe:addRows for="dataView1" rowCount="8"></xe:addRows>
                    </xp:this.script>
                </xp:eventHandler>
            </xp:link>
        </xp:this.facets>
        <xe:this.data>
            <xp:dominoView var="vwContacts" viewName="vwContacts">
            </xp:dominoView>
        </xe:this.data>
        <xe:this.summaryColumn>
            <xe:viewSummaryColumn columnName="Name"
                columnTitle="Contact">
            </xe:viewSummaryColumn>
        </xe:this.summaryColumn>
    </xe:dataView>
</xe:appPage>
```

More information...
I used a debugger to look at the HTTP requests. On the local database, here are the requests (relevant info) for the initial page and the "more" link:

```
GET .../mobilePage.xsp?$$ajaxid=view...$$viewid=!de59blf2bg! [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 20ms]
GET .../mobilePage.xsp/getRows?$$axtarget=view:_id...$$viewid=!de59blf2b5!&first=8&rows=8&state=false [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 30ms]
```

On the local preview, the "viewid" parameter is the same between requests. On the server, it's different:

```
GET .../mobilePage.xsp?$$ajaxid=view...$$viewid=!de59cuxasl! [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 30ms]
GET .../mobilePage.xsp/getRows?$$axtarget=view:_id...$$viewid=!de59cwhsqv!&first=8&rows=8&state=false [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 210ms]
no element found
```

I'm guessing that's the reason, but I don't know what's causing it or how to fix it.

Comment: Any filter/firewall between you and the server? You could use Apache TCPMon on the server to have a look what actually arrives there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of scenarios (thank goodness for virtual machines) and lots of debugging, I figured it out. It turns out that there was nothing wrong with the Extension Library. It came back to a URL redirection I had on the server for historical purposes. I had a URL redirection that converted "!" to "?". That was an old trick to get documents to appear to search engines. I got rid of those URL redirection documents, restarted HTTP, and everything works.

Answer (score 0):

on the xe:appPage try setting resetContent="true"

Comment: That didn't do it, Paul. It's still changing the $$viewid in the URL and giving the "no element found". And I actually don't want resetContent on that appPage - when I go to another appPage and back to this one, I want the user to be back to where they were.